# How to do port Forwarding. I'm using Beetel router

Tags: wampserver, portforwarding

I'm using WAMP Server which is running on port 85.I want to use NO-IP to access my site which on the server,getting problem in port forwarding.S, how can I access my site using NO-IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO-IP will only forward port 80, so you will have to use your router to forward incoming port 80 to WAMPServer-PC ip address port 85.

Its SOOooo much easier to leave Apache on port 80.

If you are not sure how to do the port forwarding [help is available here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Beetel/default.htm)